# How do you get views to flash red when clicked?

Tags: android, click

I've noticed that in most stock Android apps when you click on a View of pretty much any sort, the background of the View briefly flashes red before proceeding with whatever it's supposed to do.

I can't figure out how to do this. In some cases it seems to be built in, but not always. The Button objects I have in my Activity all flash red when clicked and I didn't have to do anything to make that happen. However, the items in my ListView do not. Each row in my ListView corresponds to a ViewGroup containing multiple other views. I want the whole row (ViewGroup) to flash red when it's clicked.

I should also point out that, functionally, everything is working properly. I click on my list item and it responds just as I designed it. It just doesn't flash red. Anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add this to your main layout used for your items in your list :

```
android:addStatesFromChildren="true" android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
```

When one child is selected then all the parent (i.e your layout / the whole row as you said) will get selected, same for other states as pressed, etc. And the selector will apply a short transistion.

Btw, red is vendor dependent, on my Archos, it's a nice orange.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: android:background was the magic attribute that I was missing. Thanks!